# Android displaying images in a gallery on main menu?

Tags: android

I want to create a main menu with a gallery that gets images from my website.

and shows them in the gallery for a user to scroll through and see upcoming event pictures.

The images will change just about every month. What is the best way to go about achieving this?

I was thinking maybe storing the images in a particular directory and having a URL set to the image.

The only question is... What happens when the images change? How would i go about updating the URL in the application? No way right?

Another thing... When the images are scrolled off the screen how do we make these images where they wont reload when out of view, causing unnecessary use of bandwidth and possibly outofmemory error.

So from what i have discovered so far, What is the best way a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the urls in a database, have the app download a small text file upon launch containing the newest urls. if there is a difference, then download the new images and update the links in the database.

Comment: And thats what ive been trying to do. the only problem is when the images are out of view they reloaded over and over again which is using to much cpu and bandwidth. its in a asyncTask but thats till no help.